# Writing the F# recursive folder visitor in C# - seq vs IEnumerable

Tags: c#, f#

I often use this recursive 'visitor' in F#

```
let rec visitor dir filter= 
    seq { yield! Directory.GetFiles(dir, filter)
          for subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(dir) do yield! visitor subdir filter}
```

Recently I've started working on implementing some F# functionality in C#, and I'm trying to reproduce this as IEnumerable, but I'm having difficulty getting any further than this:

```
static IEnumerable<string> Visitor(string root, string filter)
{
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(root, filter))
        yield return file;
    foreach (var subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(root))
        foreach (var file in Visitor(subdir, filter))
            yield return file;
}
```

What I don't understand is why I have to do a double foreach in the C# version for the recursion, but not in F#... Does the seq {} implicitly do a 'concat'?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`yield!` does a 'flatten' operation, so it integrates the sequence you passed it into the outer sequence, implicitly performing a `foreach` over each element of the sequence and `yield` on each one.

Comment: So could I do do a .SelectMany to reproduce this in C#?

Comment: C#'s `yield return` can only return one item at a time, so you're stuck with your foreaches, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

There is no simple way to do this.
You could workaround this by defining a C# type that can store either one value or a sequence of values - using the F# notation it would be:

```
type EnumerationResult<'a> = 
  | One of 'a
  | Seq of seq<'a>
```

(translate this to C# in any way you like :-))

Now, you could write something like:

```
static IEnumerable<EnumerationResult<string>> Visitor
       (string root, string filter) {
   foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(root, filter))
      yield return EnumerationResult.One(file);
      foreach (var subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(root))
           yield return EnumerationResult.Seq(Visitor(subdir, filter))
   }
}
```

To use it, you'd have to write a function that flattens EnumerationResult, which could be an extension method in C# with the following signature:

```
IEnumerable<T> Flatten(this IEnumerable<EnumerationResult<T>> res);
```

Now, this is a part where it gets tricky - if you implemented this in a straighforward way, it would still contain "forach" to iterate over the nested "Seq" results. However, I believe that you could write an optimized version that wouldn't have quadratic complexity.

Ok.. I guess this is a topic for a blog post rather than something that could be fully described here :-), but hopefully, it shows an idea that you can try following!

*[EDIT: But of course, you can also use naive implementation of "Flatten" that would use "SelectMany" just to make the syntax of your C# iterator code nicer]*

Answer (score 2):

In the specific case of retrieving all files under a specific directory, [this overload of `Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) works best:

```
static IEnumerable<string> Visitor( string root, string filter ) {
  return Directory.GetFiles( root, filter, SearchOption.AllDirectories );
}
```

In the general case of traversing a tree of enumerable objects, a nested foreach loop or equivalent is required (see also: [All About Iterators](http://blogs.msdn.com/wesdyer/archive/2007/03/23/all-about-iterators.aspx)).

---

**Edit:** Added an example of a function to flatten any tree into an enumeration:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>( T item, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> next ) {
  yield return item;
  foreach( T child in next( item ) )
    foreach( T flattenedChild in Flatten( child, next ) )
      yield return flattenedChild;
}
```

This can be used to select all nested files, as before:

```
static IEnumerable<string> Visitor( string root, string filter ) {
  return Flatten( root, dir => Directory.GetDirectories( dir ) )
    .SelectMany( dir => Directory.GetFiles( dir, filter ) );
}
```

Comment: Actually, that particular overload has a serious practical issue; namely that if *any* file or directory within the search space is invalid by virtue of having a too-long path or the user not having the appropriate permissions or any other IO exception, the entire operation is aborted and returns no results.  By contrast, using a manually recursive search, there are no such issues; you can try-catch each directory's listing individually.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, I use the following code for this kind of function:

```
public static IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> TryGetDirectories(this DirectoryInfo dir) {
    return F.Swallow(() => dir.GetDirectories(), () => new DirectoryInfo[] { });
}
public static IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> DescendantDirs(this DirectoryInfo dir) {
    return Enumerable.Repeat(dir, 1).Concat(
        from kid in dir.TryGetDirectories()
        where (kid.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) == 0
        from desc in kid.DescendantDirs()
        select desc);
}
```

This addresses IO errors (which inevitably happen, unfortunately), and avoids infinite loops due to symbolic links (in particular, you'll run into that searching some dirs in windows 7).