# F# Seq module implemented in C# for IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, f#

F# has a bunch of standard sequence operators I have come to know and love from my experience with Mathematica.  F# is getting lots of my attention now, and when it is in general release, I intend to use it frequently.

Right now, since F# isn't yet in general release, I can't really use it in production code.  LINQ implements some of these operators using SQL-like names (e.g. 'select' is 'map', and 'where' is 'filter'), but I can find no implementation of 'fold', 'iter' or 'partition'.

Has anyone seen any C# implementation of standard sequence operators?  Is this something someone should write?

Answer (score 16):

If you look carefully, many Seq operations have a LINQ equivalent or can be easily derived. Just looking down the [list](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp.core/Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Seq.html)...

- `Seq.append = Concat<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> second)`
- `Seq.concat = SelectMany<IEnumerable<TSource>, TResult>(s => s)`
- `Seq.distinct_by = GroupBy(keySelector).Select(g => g.First())`
- `Seq.exists = Any<TSource>(Func<TSource, bool> predicate)`
- `Seq.mapi = Select<TSource, TResult>(Func<TSource, Int32, TResult> selector)`
- `Seq.fold = Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate>(TAccumulate seed, Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func)`

`List.partition` is defined like this:

> Split the collection into two collections, containing the elements for which the given predicate returns `true` and `false` respectively

Which we can implement using GroupBy and a two-element array as a poor-man's tuple:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource>[] Partition<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    return source.GroupBy(predicate).OrderByDescending(g => g.Key).ToArray();
}
```

Element 0 holds the true values; 1 holds the false values. GroupBy is essentially Partition on steroids.

And finally, `Seq.iter` and `Seq.iteri` map easily to foreach:

```
public static void Iter<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> action)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
        action(item);
}

public static void IterI<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<Int32, TSource> action)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var item in source)
        action(i++, item);
}
```

Comment: Problem with your `partition` when all elements match or all fail the predicate: you get a singleton array. Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8931453/97846), inspired by yours.

Answer (score 6):

- fold = `Aggregate`

Tell use what `iter` and `partition` do, and we might fill in the blanks. I'm guessing iter=`SelectMany` and partition might involve `Skip`/`Take`?

---

(update) I looked up [Partition](http://documents.wolfram.com/mathematica/functions/Partition) - here's a crude implementation that does some of it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
static class Program { // formatted for space
    // usage
    static void Main() {
        int[] data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        var qry = data.Partition(2);

        foreach (var grp in qry) {
            Console.WriteLine("---");
            foreach (var item in grp) {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Partition<T>(
            this IEnumerable<T> source, int size) {

        int count = 0;
        T[] group = null; // use arrays as buffer
        foreach (T item in source) {
            if (group == null) group = new T[size];
            group[count++] = item;
            if (count == size) {
                yield return group;
                group = null;
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        if (count > 0) {
            Array.Resize(ref group, count);
            yield return group;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

iter exists as a method in the List class which is ForEach

otherwise :

```
public static void iter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> act) 
        {
            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                act(item);                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

ToLookup would probably be a better match for List.partition:

```
IEnumerable<T> sequence = SomeSequence();
ILookup<bool, T> lookup = sequence.ToLookup(x => SomeCondition(x));
IEnumerable<T> trueValues = lookup[true];
IEnumerable<T> falseValues = lookup[false];
```

Comment: ...except that it isn't lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Rolling your own in C# is an interesting exercise, here are a few of mine. (See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336775/pipe-forwards-in-c))

Note that iter/foreach on an IEnumerable is slightly controversial - I think because you have to 'finalise' (or whatever the word is) the IEnumerable in order for anything to actually happen.

```
    //mimic fsharp map function (it's select in c#)
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Map<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T, TResult> func)
    {
        foreach (T val in input)
            yield return func(val);
    }

    //mimic fsharp mapi function (doens't exist in C#, I think)
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> MapI<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<int, T, TResult> func)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (T val in input)
        {
            yield return func(i, val);
            i++;
        }
    }

    //mimic fsharp fold function (it's Aggregate in c#)
    public static TResult Fold<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T, TResult, TResult> func, TResult seed)
    {
        TResult ret = seed;
        foreach (T val in input)
            ret = func(val, ret);
        return ret;
    }

    //mimic fsharp foldi function (doens't exist in C#, I think)
    public static TResult FoldI<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<int, T, TResult, TResult> func, TResult seed)
    {
        int i = 0;
        TResult ret = seed;
        foreach (T val in input)
        {
            ret = func(i, val, ret);
            i++;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    //mimic fsharp iter function
    public static void Iter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Action<T> action)
    {
        input.ToList().ForEach(action);
    }
```

Comment: A mapi equivalent does exist as an overload of Select. Also, it seems a bit heavy to convert your enumerable to a list instead of doing a normal foreach loop and calling the action each time...

Comment: Didn't know about Select overload, thanks for that. ToList was the first thing that I thought of, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an update to [dahlbyk's](/a/458589/97846) `partition` solution.

It returned an `array[]` where "element 0 holds the true values; 1 holds the false values" — but this doesn't hold when all the elements match or all fail the predicate, in which case you've got a singleton array and a world of pain.

```
public static Tuple<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>> Partition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var partition = source.GroupBy(predicate);
    IEnumerable<T> matches = partition.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key) ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    IEnumerable<T> rejects = partition.FirstOrDefault(g => !g.Key) ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    return Tuple.Create(matches, rejects);
}
```