# C#: Cleanest way to divide a string array into N instances N items long

Tags: c#, arrays, string, loops

I know how to do this in an ugly way, but am wondering if there is a more elegant and succinct method.

I have a string array of e-mail addresses. Assume the string array is of arbitrary length -- it could have a few items or it could have a great many items. I want to build another string consisting of say, 50 email addresses from the string array, until the end of the array, and invoke a send operation after each 50, using the string of 50 addresses in the Send() method.

The question more generally is what's the cleanest/clearest way to do this kind of thing. I have a solution that's a legacy of my VBScript learnings, but I'm betting there's a better way in C#.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the amazing answers -- indeed your methods were vastly better than the simple looping solution I had implemented in days of yore. It was exactly the kind of guidance I was hoping to get!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split List into Sublists with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You want elegant and succinct, I'll give you elegant and succinct:

```
var fifties = from index in Enumerable.Range(0, addresses.Length) 
              group addresses[index] by index/50;
foreach(var fifty in fifties)
    Send(string.Join(";", fifty.ToArray());
```

Why mess around with all that awful looping code when you don't have to? You want to group things by fifties, *then group them by fifties.* 
That's what the group operator is for!

UPDATE: commenter MoreCoffee asks how this works. Let's suppose we wanted to group by threes, because that's easier to type.

```
var threes = from index in Enumerable.Range(0, addresses.Length) 
              group addresses[index] by index/3;
```

Let's suppose that there are nine addresses, indexed zero through eight

What does this query mean?

The `Enumerable.Range` is a range of nine numbers starting at zero, so `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8`.

Range variable `index` takes on each of these values in turn.

We then go over each corresponding `addresses[index]` and assign it to a group.

What group do we assign it to?  To group `index/3`.  Integer arithmetic rounds towards zero in C#, so indexes 0, 1 and 2 become 0 when divided by 3. Indexes 3, 4, 5 become 1 when divided by 3.  Indexes 6, 7, 8 become 2.

So we assign `addresses[0]`, `addresses[1]` and `addresses[2]` to group 0, `addresses[3]`, `addresses[4]` and `addresses[5]` to group 1, and so on.

The result of the query is a sequence of three groups, and each group is a sequence of three items.

Does that make sense?

Remember also that the result of the *query expression* is a *query which represents this operation*. It does not *perform* the operation until the `foreach` loop executes.

Comment: Is there an equivalently elegant solution for batching IEnumerable (i.e. when you don't know the size) other than the awful looping code?

Comment: Sure. Take a look at DTB's answer.

Comment: How does the by index/50 groups it? I know it works but I'm a bit confused with the synthax

Comment: @MoreCoffee: I've added some explanatory text.

Comment: Very clean indeed :) The generic extension methods based on your answer - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47495076/1475331).

Answer (score 14):

Seems similar to this question: [Split a collection into n parts with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438188/split-a-collection-into-n-parts-with-linq)

A modified version of *Hasan Khan*'s answer there should do the trick:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Chunk<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> list, int chunkSize)
{
    int i = 0;
    var chunks = from name in list
                 group name by i++ / chunkSize into part
                 select part.AsEnumerable();
    return chunks;
}
```

Usage example:

```
var addresses = new[] { "a@example.com", "b@example.org", ...... };

foreach (var chunk in Chunk(addresses, 50))
{
    SendEmail(chunk.ToArray(), "Buy V14gr4");
}
```

Comment: All seems a bit unnecessary to me! the string.Join method still needs to be called, and that can directly address a subrange within an array.

Comment: Nice, but we can do this without mutating "i". See my answer.

Comment: maybe i am missing something, but isnt Chunk<T> an Extension method, so shouldnt you be doing addresses.Chunk ?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the input consists of separate email address strings in a large array, not several email address in one string, right? And in the output, each batch is a single combined string.

```
string[] allAddresses = GetLongArrayOfAddresses();

const int batchSize = 50;

for (int n = 0; n < allAddresses.Length; n += batchSize)
{
    string batch = string.Join(";", allAddresses, n, 
                      Math.Min(batchSize, allAddresses.Length - n));

    // use batch somehow
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using .NET 3.5 and C# 3, something like this should work nicely:

```
string[] s = new string[] {"1", "2", "3", "4"....};

for (int i = 0; i < s.Count(); i = i + 50)
{
    string s = string.Join(";", s.Skip(i).Take(50).ToArray());
    DoSomething(s);
}
```

Comment: That skip/take stuff is unnecessary copying - there's an overload of string.Join that lets you specify a range within the array.

Comment: However, Take will not throw an exception if you specify more items than are in the array.  Your Math.Min addresses that, but I find the linq solution more readable and easier to understand.

Comment: There is a bug here. the first iteration of the loop you'll skip 0, and take 50, on the second iteration you'll skip 2500 (i became 50, so i*50 = 2500), instead of 50

Answer (score 1):

I would just loop through the array and using StringBuilder to create the list (I'm assuming it's separated by ; like you would for email). Just send when you hit mod 50 or the end.

```
void Foo(string[] addresses)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < addresses.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(addresses[i]);
        if ((i + 1) % 50 == 0 || i == addresses.Length - 1)
        {
            Send(sb.ToString());
            sb = new StringBuilder();
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append("; ");
        }
    }
}

void Send(string addresses)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to have a little bit more context on what exactly this list looks like to give a definitive answer.  For now I'm assuming that it's a semicolon delimeted list of email addresses.  If so you can do the following to get a chunked up list.

```
public IEnumerable<string> DivideEmailList(string list) {
  var last = 0;
  var cur = list.IndexOf(';');
  while ( cur >= 0 ) {
    yield return list.SubString(last, cur-last);
    last = cur + 1;
    cur = list.IndexOf(';', last);
  }
}

public IEnumerable<List<string>> ChunkEmails(string list) {
  using ( var e = DivideEmailList(list).GetEnumerator() ) {
     var list = new List<string>();
     while ( e.MoveNext() ) {
       list.Add(e.Current);
       if ( list.Count == 50 ) {
         yield return list;
         list = new List<string>();
       }
     }
     if ( list.Count != 0 ) {
       yield return list;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: actually he said he has an array of email addresses, so there is no need to split by semi-colon.

Comment: And the output is supposed to be a combined string.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simple and fast enough.The example below divides the long sentence into 15 parts,but you can pass batch size as parameter to make it dynamic.Here I simply divide using "/n".

```
 private static string Concatenated(string longsentence)
 {
     const int batchSize = 15;
     string concatanated = "";
     int chanks = longsentence.Length / batchSize;
     int currentIndex = 0;
     while (chanks > 0)
     {
         var sub = longsentence.Substring(currentIndex, batchSize);
         concatanated += sub + "/n";
         chanks -= 1;
         currentIndex += batchSize;
     }
     if (currentIndex < longsentence.Length)
     {
         int start = currentIndex;
         var finalsub = longsentence.Substring(start);
         concatanated += finalsub;
     }
     return concatanated;
 }
```

This show result of split operation.

```
 var parts = Concatenated(longsentence).Split(new string[] { "/n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

Extensions methods based on [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008974/1475331):

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitIntoChunks<T>(this T[] source, int chunkSize)
{
    var chunks = from index in Enumerable.Range(0, source.Length)
                 group source[index] by index / chunkSize;

    return chunks;
}

public static T[][] SplitIntoArrayChunks<T>(this T[] source, int chunkSize)
{
    var chunks = from index in Enumerable.Range(0, source.Length)
                 group source[index] by index / chunkSize;

    return chunks.Select(e => e.ToArray()).ToArray();
}
```