# How to break an array in 2 arrays in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, split

How can I break an array into 2 arrays in c#

for e.g I have an array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 
break it in to [1,2,3,4,5] and [6,7,8,9,10]

Comment: Refer this link, you may get some idea [Array][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367843/break-up-array-into-little-arrays

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Splitting An Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841246/c-sharp-splitting-an-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Linq

```
var a = new[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
var a1 = a.Take(a.Length / 2).ToArray();
var a2 = a.Skip(a.Length / 2).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

With Linq:

```
var source = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
var firstHalf = source.Take(source.Length/2).ToArray();
var secondHalf = source.Skip(source.Length/2).ToArray();
```

With [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx):

```
var source = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
var firstHalf = new int[source.Length/2];
var secondHalf = new int[source.Length - source.Length/2];
Array.Copy(source, firstHalf, firstHalf.Length];
Array.Copy(source, firstHalf.Length, secondHalf, 0, secondHalf.Length];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following method to split an array into 2 separate arrays

```
public void Split<T>(T[] array, int index, out T[] first, out T[] second) {
  first = array.Take(index).ToArray();
  second = array.Skip(index).ToArray();
}

public void SplitMidPoint<T>(T[] array, out T[] first, out T[] second) {
  Split(array, array.Length / 2, out first, out second);
}
```

Usage:

```
int[] myArray = new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
int[] newArray1;
int[] newArray2;

SplitMidPoint<int>(myArray, out newArray1, out newArray2);
```

From: [C# Splitting An Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841246/c-sharp-splitting-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static T[] SubArray(this T[] data, int index, int length)
    {
          T[] result = new T[length];
          Array.Copy(data, index, result, 0, length);
          return result;
    }
    public void Split(T[] Source, T[] arr1,T[] arr2)
    {
         if(source.Length == 0)
         {
            arr1 = arr2 = new T[0];
            return ;
         } 
         int half = source.Length/2;
         arr1 = source.SubArray(0, half);
         arr2 = source.SubArray(half-1, half);
    }
```