# C# batching enumerator

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, enumeration, batch-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ Partition List into Lists of 8 members.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773403/linq-partition-list-into-lists-of-8-members)

I've got an `IEnumerable<T>` and I'd like to transform it into an `IEnumerable<List<T>>` where each List is a batch of items in the same order as the original enumerator. Each batch should be `batchSize` items in length, except for the last batch which should contain leftover items, so it may be smaller than `batchSize`.

The underlying store is not a database or other store where I can push the batching into a lower level of the system. Instead, I need to accumulate the batches myself, because it's a stream of objects that I only can fetch one at a time.

The sequence is very long and fetching takes a while, so I can't package the entire enumerable into a `List<T>` or array ahead of time. Instead, I'd like to fetch `batchSize` results and then immediately start processing the first batch.

I may decide to later make the fetching asynchronous to the processing (so that processing batch 1 and fetching batch 2 can happen in parallel) but for now I'm just looking for a single-threaded solution.

Any suggestions for how to do this batched, streaming enumeration efficiently and elegantly?  Ideally I'd like to package it up into an extension method I can re-use, e.g.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count);
```

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend Jon's answer and use MoreLinq.  (found in the link above)

Comment: Agree, that sounds like a good answer. Thanks for digging up that question! If only I'd thought to google for "partition" instead of "batch". Let's close this one.