# How to group object in C# by its equality using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

**Scenario:**

I have a list of the object '`Order` and would like to group by the identical's `List<OrderLine>` property, by identical I mean same quantity of lines as well as same Sku/Quantity values in the same order' and return the list of order values grouped:

```
class Order
{
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLine> Lines { get; set; }
}

class OrderLine
{    
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }       
}
```

**Input sample:**

```
+-------------+-----+----------+
| OrderNumber | Sku | Quantity |
+-------------+-----+----------+
|           1 | A   |       10 |
|           1 | B   |       20 |
|           2 | A   |       10 |
|           3 | A   |       10 |
|           3 | B   |       20 |
+-------------+-----+----------+
```

**Output desired:**

> `Lines = Lines.Count();` the count of lines for each grouped identical
>
> `Pieces = SUM(OrderLine.Quantity);` the sum of all quantities for
>   each grouped identical orders.

```
+-----------------+-------+--------+
| TotalIdenticals | Lines | Pieces |
+-----------------+-------+--------+
|               1 |     1 |     10 |
|               2 |     2 |     30 |
+-----------------+-------+--------+
```

> I used a table representation to make it clearer. So as above there is
>   only 1 record with 1 line (order 2) and qty 10. on the other hand,
>   there are two orders with the same list of lines (order 1 and 3)

So I need that after running a linq algorithm, it would generate for me a object kind of

```
> "identical 1".Orders -> [2]
> "identical 2".Order -> [1,3]
```

**What I tried to do?**

```
var identicals = orderList.GroupBy(x => x.Lines)
                 .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                 .Select(g => g.Key)
                 .ToList();
```

The code above did not work, basicaly I just need to be able to group the Lines property (so its equality to other OrderLines), then I will be able to generate my output of lines/pieces... the only issue now is to be able to group my object order list by Lines list object similarity.

I hope I was clear in my question, if you need more details please let me know and I will add here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First step - in order to use `GroupBy()` with the `Order` and `OrderItem` classes, you have to [implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode) OR create an `EqualityComparer` for both classes.

Overriding `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` in  `Order` (based on the `Lines` property only):

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLine> Lines { get; set; }

    protected bool Equals(Order other)
    {
        var equals = OrderLinesEquals(Lines, other.Lines);

        return equals;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Order) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (Lines == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 19;

            foreach (OrderLine item in Lines.OrderBy(x => x.Sku, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                hash = hash * 31 + item.GetHashCode();
            }

            return hash;
        }
    }

    private bool OrderLinesEquals(List<OrderLine> x, List<OrderLine> y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (x == null || y == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        bool areEquivalent = x.Count == y.Count && !x.Except(y).Any();

        return areEquivalent;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Sku: {Sku ?? "[null]"}, Quantity: {Quantity}";
    }
}
```

Overriding `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` in  `OrderItem` (based on both the `Sku` and `Quantity` properties):

```
public class OrderLine
{
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    protected bool Equals(OrderLine other)
    {
        return string.Equals(Sku, other.Sku) && Quantity == other.Quantity;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((OrderLine) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return ((Sku != null ? Sku.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397) ^ Quantity;
        }
    }
}
```

Testing code - list of orders:

```
var order1 = new Order
{
    OrderNumber = 1,
    Lines = new List<OrderLine>
    {
        new OrderLine
        {
            Quantity = 10,
            Sku = "A"
        },

        new OrderLine
        {
            Quantity = 20,
            Sku = "B"
        }
    }
};

var order2 = new Order
{
    OrderNumber = 2,
    Lines = new List<OrderLine>
    {
        new OrderLine
        {
            Quantity = 10,
            Sku = "A"
        }
    }
};

var order3 = new Order
{
    OrderNumber = 3,
    Lines = new List<OrderLine>
    {
        new OrderLine
        {
            Quantity = 20,
            Sku = "B"
        },
        new OrderLine
        {
            Quantity = 10,
            Sku = "A"
        }
    }
};


var order4 = new Order
{
    OrderNumber = 4,
    Lines = new List<OrderLine>
    {
        new OrderLine
        {
            Quantity = 20,
            Sku = "B"
        },
        new OrderLine
        {
            Quantity = 10,
            Sku = "A"
        }
    }
};


var order5 = new Order
{
    OrderNumber = 5,
    Lines = new List<OrderLine>
    {
        new OrderLine
        {
            Quantity = 30,
            Sku = "C"
        }
    }
};


var order6 = new Order
{
    OrderNumber = 6,
    Lines = new List<OrderLine>
    {
        new OrderLine
        {
            Quantity = 40,
            Sku = "C"
        }
    }
};


var order7 = new Order
{
    OrderNumber = 7,
    Lines = new List<OrderLine>
    {
        new OrderLine
        {
            Quantity = 30,
            Sku = "C"
        }
    }
};

var orderList = new List<Order>(new[] {order1, order2, order3, order4, order5, order6, order7});
```

Grouping the orders:

```
var identicalOrders = orderList.GroupBy(x => x)
                               .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                               .Select(g => new
                               {
                                   Count = g.Count(),
                                   OrderItems = g.Key.Lines,
                                   OrderNumbers = orderList.Where(x => x.Equals(g.Key))
                                                           .Select(x => x.OrderNumber)
                                                           .ToList()
                               })
                               .ToList();
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Is it possible to return the Order numbers as well? the list of order number grouped together?

Comment: also, the result was wrong, it is grouping by quantity and sku, but it should compare the whole list, for example: list 1: has 2 items A,10/B,20    these values together need to find another list with both A,10/B,20 in the list.

Comment: Impressive, congrats!

Comment: Is it also possible to split the group by a specific value? such as I want to break down the group in 2 records each as max, so instead of having for example 2 groups of 10 records each, to have instead 10 groups of 2 records each if I say that I want to split in groups of max 2 records each?

Comment: @RogerOliveira see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773403/linq-partition-list-into-lists-of-8-members

Answer (score 1):

To be able to group by `Lines` you need to implement `IEqualityComparer<List<OrderLine>>` and pass it into `GroupBy` method: `var groups = orders.GroupBy(o => o.Lines, o => o, new OrderLineEqualityComparer());`

```
internal class OrderLineEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<OrderLine>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<OrderLine> x, List<OrderLine> y)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<OrderLine> obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```