# Split a collection into parts based on condition with LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, grouping

I want to achieve something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438188/split-a-collection-into-n-parts-with-linq/438513#438513). But I don't know in what manner I can use that solution.

My entity has these properties

```
CustomerName
Date
SortOrder
```

I've whole list of this Entity. What I want to do is, group all those items in List<> which have consecutive *SortOrder* and same *Date* and same *CustomerName*

**Example input**

```
  var inv = new List<Invoice>(){
    new Invoice(){ CustomerName = "Abc" ,Date = DateTime.Today, SortOrder = 0},
    new Invoice(){ CustomerName = "Abc" ,Date = DateTime.Today, SortOrder = 1},
    new Invoice(){ CustomerName = "Abc" ,Date = DateTime.Today, SortOrder = 2},
    new Invoice(){ CustomerName = "xyz" ,Date = DateTime.Today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)), SortOrder = 3},
    new Invoice(){ CustomerName = "xyz" ,Date = DateTime.Today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)), SortOrder = 4},
    new Invoice(){ CustomerName = "Abc" ,Date = DateTime.Today, SortOrder = 5},
    new Invoice(){ CustomerName = "Abc" ,Date = DateTime.Today, SortOrder = 6}
  };
```

**Example output**

```
  var invGrouped = new List<List<Invoice>>
   {
     new List<Invoice>
       {
         new Invoice {CustomerName = "Abc", Date = DateTime.Today, SortOrder = 0},
         new Invoice {CustomerName = "Abc", Date = DateTime.Today, SortOrder = 1},
         new Invoice {CustomerName = "Abc", Date = DateTime.Today, SortOrder = 2}
       },
     new List<Invoice>
       {
         new Invoice {CustomerName = "xyz", Date = DateTime.Today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)), SortOrder = 3},
         new Invoice {CustomerName = "xyz", Date = DateTime.Today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)), SortOrder = 4}
       },
     new List<Invoice>
       {
         new Invoice {CustomerName = "Abc", Date = DateTime.Today, SortOrder = 5},
         new Invoice {CustomerName = "Abc", Date = DateTime.Today, SortOrder = 6}

       }
   };
```

**UPDATE**
Non-LINQ solution will also suffice.

Comment: It would greatly help if you could include a small sample of data as well as exactly what you expect that data to look like once it has been grouped.

Comment: Why aren't the two bottom rows (with CustomerName "Abc" and DateTime of Today) in the same list as the other Customer "Abc" orders placed today?

Comment: Because the SortOrders were not consecutive ( 3 and 4 are missing).  This is what I was hoping to confirm by asking for data and desired output.

Comment: @DoctaJonez! @diceguyd30 has understood it correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one possible LINQ answer, though I'm sure a more efficient one exists:

```
    inv
        .GroupBy(x => new { CustomerName = x.CustomerName, Date = x.Date })
        .SelectMany(x => x
                            .OrderBy(y => y.SortOrder)
                            .Select((y,i) => new { Value = y, Sort = y.SortOrder - i })
                            .GroupBy(y => y.Sort)
                            .Select(y => y.Select(z => z.Value))
        )
```

Comment: +1 Thanks very much. Leaving for home right now. Will try it tomorrow.

Comment: You are great! It works amazingly!!! You saved me lot of headache and time. I'm grateful to you.