# Iterate Typed List in sections

Tags: vb.net, list, .net-2.0, c#-2.0, iteration

I have the following list

```
Dim ordersToUpdate as New List(Of OrderUpdate)
```

I am using a "For Each" to iterate and update a legacy DB

```
For Each order In ordersToUpdate

  UpdateDB(order)

Next
```

I am having a LOCKING problem on the DB when the "ordersToUpdate" is large. Instead to puting a Threading.Thread.Sleep to pause, is there a proper way to break the list up into sections e.g iterating 100 at a time?

Comment: What is the legacy DB? What kind of LOCKING problem do you have? Show us the UpdateDB-Function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Function SplitList(Of T)(ByVal list As List(Of T), ByVal size As Integer) As List(Of List(Of T))
        Dim result As New List(Of List(Of T))
        For i = 0 To CInt(Math.Ceiling(list.Count / size)) - 1
            result.Add(New List(Of T)(list.GetRange(i * size, Math.Min(size, list.Count - (i * size)))))
        Next
        Return result
    End Function
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438188/split-a-collection-into-n-parts-with-linq)