# Convert string of numbers to array of numbers c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, int

I have a string of 9 space-separated integers, like `"3 4 6 9 8 8 2 3 4"`, which I want to convert to a 3x3 int Array.

A simple solution is to do two loops over a new matrix and convert string values 
as I go. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: You might want to specify where you want the rectangular array [,] or the jagged one [][].

Comment: i want the array to be  rectangular  thanks Dmitri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using my Split extension from [Split a collection into `n` parts with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438188/split-a-collection-into-n-parts-with-linq/438513#438513)

```
var nums = s.Split(' ').Select(n=>Int32.Parse(n)).ToList();
var grid = nums.Split(nums.Count / 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your solution is as good as you can go.  You can accomplish the same thing with LINQ:

```
int[][] result = 
    s.Split(' ')
     .Select((a, index) => new {index, value = int.Parse(a)})
     .GroupBy(tuple => tuple.index / 3)
     .Select(g => g.Select(tuple => tuple.value).ToArray())
     .ToArray();
```

For this problem, the LINQ solution is probably worse than the normal solution; however, the idea may be helpful for similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an split over the " " character string.split() and you will get an array of string with the numbers. Then you must cast them to integers and distribute a plain array to you desired array and as far as I know there is no way to do that in another way that iterating through the array, but you will need only 1 loop.