# How to partitioning or splitting DataTable in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I want to split DataTable so that I can upload its chunks from one place to other.

For example

> pick first 100 rows.
>   pick next 100 rows.
>   pick next 100 rows and so on ...

Is there any way to do it just like cursor in Database? I do not like to use loops etc. for counting rows.

Comment: Use linq  select part of record 
see this link In Stack Over flow
[Split a collection into n parts with LINQ?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438188/split-a-collection-into-n-parts-with-linq

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split List into Sublists with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`YourDataTable.Select()` gives you an array of Data

What about linq?

Fro example `YourDataTable.Select (x => x).Take (100).ToEnumerable()` gives you the first 100 `DataRows` and `YourDataTable.Select (x => x).Skip(100).Take (100).ToEnumerable()` for the next 100.

Comment: use Skip()  like `.Skip(100).Take(100)`

Comment: @Yahia, Getting an error as "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type". Looks like a lambda expresssion cannot be used in DataTable.Select() method.

Comment: You are assuming it is always 100?

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
public static class DataExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<DataRow>> Partition(this DataTable dataTable, int partitionSize)
    {
        var numRows = Math.Ceiling((double)dataTable.Rows.Count);
        for(var i = 0; i < numRows / partitionSize; i++)
        {
            yield return Partition(dataTable, i * partitionSize, i * partitionSize + partitionSize);
        }
    }
    private static IEnumerable<DataRow> Partition(DataTable dataTable, int index, int endIndex)
    {
        for(var i = index; i < endIndex && i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            yield return dataTable.Rows[i];
        }
    }
}
var partitions = dataTable.Partition(100);
```

Doing:

```
dataTable.Skip(0).Take(100);
dataTable.Skip(100).Take(100);
dataTable.Skip(200).Take(100);
dataTable.Skip(300).Take(100);
```

Will iterate 0 times, and take 100 on the first execution. Then iterate through 100 rows, take 100, then iterate 200 rows, then take 100, etc.

The above will do a lazy fetch and only hit each row once

Comment: This is the best answer for performance, using multiple linq calls as mentioned in the text above will result in additional unnecessary iterations through the entire data set. This answer avoids that problem.

Comment: How do i convert this to vb.net?

Comment: How might I go about implementing `foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Skip(300).Take(100))` ?

Comment: Until now I didn't know i needed that extension :D

Answer (score 3):

This is a simply way to do that:

```
public DataSet test(DataSet ds, int max)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 1;
        DataSet newDs = new DataSet();
        DataTable newDt = ds.Tables[0].Clone();
        newDt.TableName = "Table_" + j;
        newDt.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            DataRow newRow = newDt.NewRow();
            newRow.ItemArray = row.ItemArray;

            newDt.Rows.Add(newRow);
            i++;
            if (i == max)
            {
                newDs.Tables.Add(newDt);
                j++;                    
                newDt = ds.Tables[0].Clone();
                newDt.TableName = "Table_" + j;
                newDt.Clear();
                i = 0;
            }
        }
        return newDs;
    }
```

Can you try?

Comment: Before you return newDs, you'll need to add the last newDt!

Comment: This code has a major flaw:

It only adds the created DataTable to the tables List once i == max, this means that the last DataTable wont be added unless the table size is divisible by chunk size.

To remedy that move/add the newDs.Tables.Add(newDt); to immediately after the two table creations

Answer (score 2):

Use linq  select part of record 
this link in stack overflow can be helpful
[Split a collection into n parts with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438188/split-a-collection-into-n-parts-with-linq)

Answer (score 1):

Check: [splitting a large datatable into smaller batches from c-sharpcorner.com](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/14259/splitting-a-large-datatable-into-smaller-batches.aspx)

```
internal static List<datatable> SplitTable(DataTable originalTable, int batchSize)
    {
        List<datatable> tables = new List<datatable>();

        DataTable new_table = new DataTable();
        new_table = originalTable.Clone();
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;

        if (originalTable.Rows.Count &lt;= batchSize)
        {
            new_table.TableName = "Table_" + k;
            new_table = originalTable.Copy();
            tables.Add(new_table.Copy());
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i &lt; originalTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                new_table.NewRow();
                new_table.ImportRow(originalTable.Rows[i]);
                if ((i + 1) == originalTable.Rows.Count)
                {
                    new_table.TableName = "Table_" + k;
                    tables.Add(new_table.Copy());
                    new_table.Rows.Clear();
                    k++;
                }
                else if (++j == batchSize)
                {
                    new_table.TableName = "Table_" + k;
                    tables.Add(new_table.Copy());
                    new_table.Rows.Clear();
                    k++;
                    j = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        return tables;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Improving on  @vanessa

public DataSet SplitDataTable(DataTable tableData, int max)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int j = 1;
            int countOfRows = tableData.Rows.Count;
            DataSet newDs = new DataSet();
            DataTable newDt = tableData.Clone();
            newDt.TableName = tableData.TableName+"_" + j;
            newDt.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow row in tableData.Rows)
            {
                DataRow newRow = newDt.NewRow();
                newRow.ItemArray = row.ItemArray;

                newDt.Rows.Add(newRow);
                i++;

                countOfRows--;

                if (i == max )
                {
                    newDs.Tables.Add(newDt);
                    j++;
                    newDt = tableData.Clone();
                    newDt.TableName = tableData.TableName + "_" + j;
                    newDt.Clear();
                    i = 0;
                }

                if (countOfRows == 0 && i < max)
                {
                    newDs.Tables.Add(newDt);
                    j++;
                    newDt = tableData.Clone();
                    newDt.TableName = tableData.TableName + "_" + j;
                    newDt.Clear();
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
            return newDs;
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just throw your source code here. Be nice and try to give a nice description to your answer, so that others will like it and upvote it. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)