# Split C# MultiSelectList into smaller ones using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have a MultiSelectList that I want to split into several smaller MultiSelectList, depending on the value (NOT the selectedValues), and I want to use LINQ to achieve that...sure it is possible but I can't cut it..any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: can we see some code and what you are referring by `value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you want:

```
var multiSelectList= new MultiSelectList(new List<string>()); //your mutli-select list
var multiSelectListGroupedByValue=ms.GroupBy(x => x.Value)
                                  .Select(x=>new MultiSelectList(x.Select(y=>y.Value)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code (get it from here [Split a collection into `n` parts with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438188/split-a-collection-into-n-parts-with-linq))

```
static class LinqExtensions
{
 public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int parts)
 {
     int i = 0;
     var splits = from item in list
                  group item by i++ % parts into part
                  select part.AsEnumerable();
     return splits;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you need

```
@{
    var array = new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
}

@Html.ListBox("lstBoxLessThan5",new MultiSelectList(array.Where(a => a < 5).ToArray()));
<br />
@Html.ListBox("lstBoxMorethan5",new MultiSelectList(array.Where(a => a > 5).ToArray()));
```

Put whatever business logic inplace of temp datastructure 'array'