# Linq Get next n records

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have a grid with pager, I am trying to get the next 25 records starting with a start index.

for example for the first time it I return 25 records, when I change to next I want to pick the next 25 records and skip the first 25.

What is the most preferable way to do it using LINQ?

Thanks,
Alaa

Comment: I think that is the best approach I got to,
  uvs = uvs.Skip(startIndex.Value * recordsCount.Value).Take(recordsCount.Value);

is there any better solution for performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use use the [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) and [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) methods

```
var list = source.Skip(25 * page).Take(25);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want better performance, you can partition your collection of records into groups of 25: here's a  [simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6362642/480799) and an [efficient solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/438208/480799).

Remember that each time an IEnumerable gets enumerated, the statement that created it gets executed, so be sure to use ToList() when appropriate.