# Split datatable into multiple fixed sized tables

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a data table which has 1123 records. I want to split this table into 5 fixed size separate datatables. Size limit for each table is 225.

So size of resulting datatables will be:

```
DT1 : 225 rows
DT2 : 225 rows
DT3 : 225 rows
DT4 : 225 rows
DT5 : 223 rows (remaining rows)
```

I was able to find how to split datatable based on the column value using LINQ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740353/split-a-datatable-into-2-or-more-datatables-based-on-column-value).

I also found a way to split datatable into multiple tables [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/splitting-a-large-datatable-into-smaller-batches1). Wanted to know if there's a better way of doing this. Posting code form the link:

```
private static List<DataTable> SplitTable(DataTable originalTable, int batchSize)
{
     List<DataTable> tables = new List<DataTable>();
     int i = 0;
     int j = 1;
    DataTable newDt = originalTable.Clone();
   newDt.TableName = "Table_" + j;
   newDt.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow row in originalTable.Rows)
    {
         DataRow newRow = newDt.NewRow();
         newRow.ItemArray = row.ItemArray;
         newDt.Rows.Add(newRow);
         i++;
         if (i == batchSize)
        {
           tables.Add(newDt);
           j++;
          newDt = originalTable.Clone();
          newDt.TableName = "Table_" + j;
          newDt.Clear();
          i = 0;
      }
  }
   return tables;
}
```

Need help in splitting datatable into fixed size.

Comment: What's wrong with the current way that you are doing it..? is it yielding the 5 tables with 225 records each in them..?

Comment: it working well. I am worried about the efficiency. The actual data on which this function will be operating will be large. Also its always better to code in a small set of lines.

Comment: Actually, this question is more appropriate at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @GertArnold It doesn't sound like the author's code is working correctly yet ("Need help in splitting datatable into fixed size") which would mean it is off-topic on Code Review, until it works as the author intends. If you have any questions or concerns, join us at our [CR Help Desk](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34045).

Comment: Ah, okay. Then if it is working well but they want to improve efficiency, this would be OK for Code Review.

Comment: you can check this one https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/4057734/Split-DataTable-into-Multiple-DataTables-Csharp

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I once made this little [extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6852288/861716):

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> ToChunks<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable,
                                                      int chunkSize)
{
    int itemsReturned = 0;
    var list = enumerable.ToList(); // Prevent multiple execution of IEnumerable.
    int count = list.Count;
    while (itemsReturned < count)
    {
        int currentChunkSize = Math.Min(chunkSize, count - itemsReturned);
        yield return list.GetRange(itemsReturned, currentChunkSize);
        itemsReturned += currentChunkSize;
    }
}
```

that cuts any `IEnumerable` into chunks of the specified chunk size.

Having this, you can simply do:

```
var tables = originalTable.AsEnumerable().ToChunks(225)
                          .Select(rows => rows.CopyToDataTable())
```

The reason why this could perform better than a straightforward `foreach` is that `list.GetRange` is a very efficient method to get a range of rows from a list. I curious to know what you'll find out.

Comment: @GertArnold How can I make a vb.net version for this, as vb does not support yield?

Comment: I am using VS 2008

Comment: How can I loop through it to get column data using `foreach(DataRow in tables)` ?

Comment: Outstanding solution! Thanks

Comment: @GertArnold i use your extension method for split datatable with 5 million rows but i get out of memory exception, i can help me to avoid this exception, out of memory at `System.Data.Common.StringStorage.SetCapacity(Int32 capacity)`

Comment: @HasanFathi Not from a single comment. You should post this in a new question. Or try a streaming solution with Skip/Take, which will take considerably longer but won't eat that much memory.

Comment: A far better method with lazy evaluation, possible by more modern C# syntax, is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68902864/861716).

Answer (score 2):

```
private static List<DataTable> SplitTable(DataTable originalTable, int batchSize)
    {
        List<DataTable> tables = new List<DataTable>();
        int i = 0;
        int j = 1;
        DataTable newDt = originalTable.Clone();
        newDt.TableName = "Table_" + j;
        newDt.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow row in originalTable.Rows)
        {
            DataRow newRow = newDt.NewRow();
            newRow.ItemArray = row.ItemArray;
            newDt.Rows.Add(newRow);
            i++;
            if (i == batchSize)
            {
                tables.Add(newDt);
                j++;
                newDt = originalTable.Clone();
                newDt.TableName = "Table_" + j;
                newDt.Clear();
                i = 0;
            }



        }
        if (newDt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            tables.Add(newDt);
            j++;
            newDt = originalTable.Clone();
            newDt.TableName = "Table_" + j;
            newDt.Clear();

        }
        return tables;
    }



 foreach (var dt1 in SplitTable(table1, 2))
        {
            DataTable dt = dt1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it for lazy people :)

```
private static DataTable GetDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> data, int skip, int take)
        {
            var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

            var dataTable = new DataTable();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                dataTable
                    .Columns
                    .Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType)
                                    ?? prop.PropertyType);

            foreach (var item in data.Skip(skip).Take(take))
            {
                var row = dataTable.NewRow();
                foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                    row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;

                dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return dataTable;
        }
```

And client will call it like this:

```
 var nthDataTable = GetDataTable(model, skip: n, take: m);
```

Comment: I want to split it and then take each 1000 record can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688229/how-to-split-data-table-into-multiple-tables-with-adding-1-minute-delay)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm too late, but the best way i found was this, setting my datatable into List of DataRows

```
    public static List<DataTable> Testes(DataTable yourDataTableToSplit, int numberOfDatatablesYouWant) 
    {
        List<DataRow> rows = yourDataTableToSplit.AsEnumerable().ToList();
        List<DataTable> result = new List<DataTable>();
        int rowsToTake = yourDataTableToSplit.Rows.Count / numberOfDatatablesYouWant;
        while (rows.Count > 0)
        {
            result.Add(rows.Take(rowsToTake).CopyToDataTable());
            rows = rows.Skip(rowsToTake).ToList();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

i used it to bulk insert data on sqlserver, like this:

```
        public static List<string> DataBulkInsert(DataTable dtDataInsert, SqlConnection conn, string tableName)
        {
            List<string> errors = new List<string>();
            int batchSize = dtDataInsert.Rows.Count;

            bool lastEntry= false;

            List<DataRow> bulkData = dtDataInsert.AsEnumerable().ToList();

            while (bulkData.Count() > 0 && batchSize > 0)
            {
                bulkData = SQLBulkInsert(bulkData, conn, dtDataInsert.TableName, batchSize , ref errors);
                if (batchSize % 2 == 0)
                    batchSize /= 2;
                else if (batchSize > 1)
                    batchSize = (batchSize + 1) / 2;
                else if (batchSize == 1 && !lastEntry)
                    lastEntry= true;
                else
                    batchSize = 0;
            }

            return errors.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
        }

        public static List<DataRow> SQLBulkInsert(List<DataRow> listToInsert, SqlConnection conn, string tableName, int batchSize, ref List<string> erros)
        {

            List<DataRow> dataError = new List<DataRow>();
            List<DataRow> dataToTry = listToInsert.Take(batchSize).ToList();

            while (dataToTry.Count() > 0)
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
                {
                    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 120;
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                    try
                    {
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataToTry.CopyToDataTable());
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        errors.Add(ex.Message);
                        dataError.AddRange(dataToTry);
                    }

                    listToInsert = listToInsert.Skip(batchSize).ToList();
                    dataToTry = listToInsert.Take(batchSize).ToList();
                }
            }
            return dataError;
        }
```

Comment: This is the same idea that the poster was applying in the question, right?  The question was asking for a more efficient way to do it.  This answer just reposts working code that the OP already had years ago.

Comment: I agree. And why such a specialized method? A generic method is a versatile tool that serves an entire code base and can be used here just as well.

Comment: BTW, you may want to rename your method, it's a bit... ambiguous.

Comment: For sure, i just show how i used, not really the method or variables names that i used in my code.
I think if use linq istead of foreach is a faster way to do it than the showed in the question.

Answer (score -1):

The solutions given here did not work for me, if the last set of records is less than the desired size of chunk datatable then it will simply ignore those records and resulting in losing them.. for ex if there are 5 records and chunk table size is 2 then it will create only 2 datatable ignoring the last record.

Here is the corrected code which worked for me in all scenarios.

Users working on VB.NET may or may not be able to use LINQ many a times so if you need vb.net code of the same then take a look here [Split large datatable into chunks in c# and vb.net](http://codeanalyze.com/Articles/Details/20197/Break-datatable-into-multiple-chunks-split-datatable-into-multiple-small-datatables)

```
 private static List<DataTable> SplitTable(DataTable mainTable, int batchSize)
{
    List<DataTable> tables = new List<DataTable>();
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    int rowCount = 0;
    DataTable tempDt = mainTable.Clone();
    tempDt.TableName = "ChunkDataTable" + j.ToString();
    tempDt.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow row in mainTable.Rows) {
        rowCount += 1;
        DataRow newRow = tempDt.NewRow();
        newRow.ItemArray = row.ItemArray;
        tempDt.Rows.Add(newRow);
        i += 1;
        if (i == batchSize | rowCount == mainTable.Rows.Count) {
            tables.Add(tempDt);
            j += 1;
            tempDt = mainTable.Clone();
            tempDt.TableName = "ChunkDataTable" + j.ToString();
            tempDt.Clear();
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    return tables;
}
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer but LINQ is available and has always been available in both VB and C#

Comment: *simply ignore those records* Not with my solution.