# Creating sub arrays using LINQ

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split List into Sublists with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq)
>   [Split a collection into n parts with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438188/split-a-collection-into-n-parts-with-linq)

I have an array like this:

```
[1,2,4,5.....n]
```

I would like to convert it in sub arrays like this:

```
[
   [1,2,3],
   [4,5,6],
   ...
]
```

Basically I want to group the array in groups of **n** members

Is there any LINQ function to help me to accomplish this??

I was thinking in the `GroupBy` or `SelectMany` but I have not figured out how to do it

Note, I already did this using a `foreach` statement, but I would like to do it using LINQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        int[] ar = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        var gr = ar
            .Select( (e, i) => new {e, p=i/3})
            .GroupBy( e => e.p )
            .Select( g => g
                .Select(e => e.e)
                .ToArray()
            )
            .ToArray();
```