# Extension method throws exception only when debugging

Tags: c#, exception, extension-methods

I am using the following extension method ([from an existing StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438188/split-a-collection-into-n-parts-with-linq)) to split an existing enumerable into two:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int parts)
{
    int i = 0;
    var splits = from item in list
                 group item by i++ % parts into part
                 select part.AsEnumerable();
    return splits;
}
```

I am using the method like so:

```
//accountIds is simply an IEnumerable<string>
var foo = accountIds.Split(2).ToList();
```

The method seemingly works fine when I run my application.  However, when I debug my application this line of code always throws an exception:

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I am very confused why this method only throws an exception when I am debugging.

Comment: Mutating a variable inside a query is a worst practice. Don't do this in the first place. Why it is crashing I don't know but there are better ways to split a sequence.

Comment: did you look on your `foo` if it has any elements inside it?

Comment: @FreddieFabregas - If I remove the `.ToList()` call I avoid the exception and I am returned two enumerables each with ~1300 elements.

Comment: Have you tried to narrow down the issue at all and isolating it away from your current project? I created the same thing and had no issue, but I don't know what exactly accountIds looks like, so I can only guess.

Comment: @Corylulu - Yes.  I should have been more specific, but, `accountIds` is nothing more than a list of strings.  My real project example is pretty simple.

Comment: @Ek0nomik Okay, well I have no problem stepping through this in debugger: http://pastie.org/6345471 Is this a fair representation of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about this, but I think you should evaluate it first. You can use `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` method.

Have a look on Jon Skeet [blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2007/10/15/fun-with-captured-variables.aspx) on captured variables.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite understanding.  I already am calling `.ToList()` which results in the error.  Or are you saying that I should be calling `.ToList()` inside the extension method?

Comment: reverse the logic to this: var foo = accountIds.ToList().Split(2);