# Split array to smaller arrays using linq?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an unknown size array and I want to fragment it to small sized arrays.

For example 733 items array will become list of 7 100 item arrays and one 33 item array.

```
List<List<T>> Split(List<T> list, uint sublistsize)
```

I can write some code to do this but is there something built in?

Comment: Also, note that a list is different (but similar) to an array.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438188/split-a-collection-into-n-parts-with-linq

Comment: I was thinking [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6362642/265419) from the suggested duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
static List<List<T>> Split<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int sublistsize)
{
    return list.Select((i, idx) => new { Item = i, Index = idx })
         .GroupBy(x => x.Index / sublistsize)
         .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.Item).ToList())
         .ToList();
}
```