# displaying three cells of data per row in Html Table

Tags: c#, html, code-behind

was hoping for some help on displaying three cells of data per row of an Html table looping through a collection of string values.

Displayed as follow

value1


value2


value3





value4


value5


value6

Was thinking on something along the lines of this

```
sb.Append("<table");
sb.Append("<tbody>");

            for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
            {
                var subjectName = items[i].toString();
                if (i % 3 == 0)
                {
                   sb.Append("<tr>");
                   sb.Append("<td>");
                   sb.Append("<a href='url'>" + subjectName + "</a>");
                   sb.Append("</td>");
                   sb.Append("</tr>");
                }
                else
                 {
                   sb.Append("<td>");
                   sb.Append("<a href='url'>" + subjectName + "</a>");
                   sb.Append("</td>"); 
                 }
            }

            sb.Append("</tbody>");
            sb.Append("</table>");
```

but the display looks terrible
Help perhaps
regards

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: I am trying to display a sequence of three cells of data before the next row starts for another three

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the row definition outside of the for loop like this:

```
sb.Append("<table");
sb.Append("<tbody>");

sb.Append("<tr>"); //will only create one row with 3 cells inside   
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    var subjectName = items[i].toString();

    sb.Append("<td>");
    sb.Append("<a href='url'>" + subjectName + "</a>");
    sb.Append("</td>");
}
sb.Append("</tr>"); 

sb.Append("</tbody>");
sb.Append("</table>");´
```

If you want to do several rows with 1 or more cells you have to use 2 for loops, 1 that enumerates threw your rows and 1 to enumerate your cells content something like:

```
    sb.Append("<table");
    sb.Append("<tbody>");

for (int j = 0; j < rows.count; j++)
{
    sb.Append("<tr>"); //create the number of rows you have specified in the j for loop  
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        var subjectName = items[i].toString();

        sb.Append("<td>");
        sb.Append("<a href='url'>" + subjectName + "</a>");
        sb.Append("</td>");
    }
    sb.Append("</tr>"); 
}
    sb.Append("</tbody>");
    sb.Append("</table>");´
```

Comment: If items.Count is 6 you will get 1 row with 6 cells

Answer (score 0):

I would use a partinioning method (like jon skeet's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/438208/792715)). Then just use a double loop to create the rows like this

```
foreach (var row in items.Partition(3))
{
    sb.Append("<tr>");
    foreach (var subjectName in row)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("<td><a href='url'>{0}</a></td>", subjectName);
    }
    sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
}
```