# Split Big list to Small list in C# without use LINQ

Tags: c#, mongodb, list

Is there a nice way to split a collection into 'n' parts in other list in C#  , I have big list of Bson Documents about 1 Millions items and need to split this in multiple list ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a collection into n parts with LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438188/split-a-collection-into-n-parts-with-linq)

Comment: I can not used its not work with BSONDcouments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if linq support Mongodb
then you may do some thing like that

```
return result.Skip(rowstoSkip).Take(listlength).Tolist();
```

as result is your query,
rowtoSkip is the count of rows you take in previous lists,
listLength is the required length of sub list.