# C# - Distribute strings in a 3 group programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, algorithm

```
string[] names = new string[6]
names[0] = "Person 1";
names[1] = "Person 2";
names[2] = "Person 3";
names[3] = "Person 4";
names[4] = "Person 5";
names[5] = "Person 6";
```

I have a string array like this. I'm distribute this strings in a 3 group in order with labels like this:

> [My Windows Form . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . [X]]
> |GROUP A | GROUP B | GROUP C|
>   |Person 1 .|. Person 3 .|. Person 5|
>   |Person 2 .|. Person 4 .|. Person 6|

How can I do that on between 18-23 string arrays and write in 3 Group Boxes?

Comment: What does it means: How can I do that on between 18-23 string arrays?

Comment: Related : [Split a collection into n parts with LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438188/split-a-collection-into-n-parts-with-linq)

Comment: new string[ThErE](); ThErE value is changing on all openings of this application. (Sorry for my English. I'm not English :()

Comment: @Sehnsucht It does not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] names = new string[6];
names[0] = "Person 1";
names[1] = "Person 2";
names[2] = "Person 3";
names[3] = "Person 4";
names[4] = "Person 5";
names[5] = "Person 6";

var result = Enumerable.Range(0, names.Length / 3)
                       .Select(i => new string[] { names[i], names[i+1], names[i+2] })
                       .ToArray();
```

Here this should create your `string[][]`

After that using `StringBuilder` you can build your result:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("[My Windows Form. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . [X]]");
sb.AppendLine("|GROUP A | GROUP B | GROUP C|");

foreach (var item in result)
{
    sb.AppendLine($"|{item[0]}|{item[1]}|{item[2]}");
}

string result = sb.ToString();
```

Here: [**Full Example in DotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/flkxDo)

If you don't have `i%3 == 0` items in the names, you can do it like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("[My Windows Form. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . [X]]");
sb.AppendLine("|GROUP A | GROUP B | GROUP C|");
for (int i=0;i < names.Length; i++)
{
    if((i+1) % 3 == 0)
    {
        sb.AppendLine($"|{names[i]}|");
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append($"|{names[i]}");
    }
}

string result = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: I want a person in each group that is not in another group. This code adds the same people to different groups.

Comment: You can do it using sb.Append() and sb.AppendLine() and looking for i% 3 ==0 without making them in one array.