# What should be a Parallel.For equivalent of this loop

Tags: vb.net, parallel-processing, parallel.for

I have this sequential loop in vb.net.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 615 Step 15
    DownloadSingleFile(i)
Next
```

The "Step 15" part in the loop is important.
I'm unable to figure out a parallel substitute for this code.

I tried the below code, but it is missing the "Step 15" part.

```
Parallel.For(0, 615, Sub(i)
                 DownloadSingleFile(i)
                     End Sub)
```

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parallelizing a for loop with stepping in .net 4.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593342/parallelizing-a-for-loop-with-stepping-in-net-4-5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the same:

42 (exclusive) = ((615 / 15) + 1)

```
Parallel.For(0, 42, Sub(i)
      DownloadSingleFile(i * 15)
 End Sub)
```

Comment: I cannot believe I missed your answer. Anyhow, I deleted mine, and updated yours.

Comment: +1. Another suggestion is to use Enumerable.Range http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045112/parallel-for-using-step-1.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I know you'd do the same for me;)