# .Net: Empty string is not clear space character?

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, null

I've always use String.IsNullOrEmpty to check for a empty string. It recently come to my attention that a " " count as not a empty string. For example,

```
 Dim test As String = " "
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(test) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Empty String")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Not Emtpy String")
    End If
```

It will show "Not Empty String". So how do we check for " " or "        " in a string?

edit: I wasn't aware that " " count as character.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this method to check for blank strings.  It is different from the Trim() versions in that it does not allocate a new string.  It also uses a more expanded notion of whitespace.

```
Public Function IsNullOrBlank(ByVal str as String) As Boolean
  if String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) Then
    Return True
  End IF
  For Each c In str
    IF Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(c) Then
      Return False
    End If
  Next
  Return True
End Function
```

Comment: Ohh the top of your head do you know what the associated cost of using Trim vs this?

Comment: @Josh no, that would require a profiler :). I imagine they are close to the same speed as they do roughly the same thing.  The main difference is the allocation of the string

Comment: Trim() would at worst copy n-1 characters from your original string into a new one (if there was one leading or trailing white space). At best it would return the empty string (if it was already empty or blank) or the original string (if there were no leading or trailing white space).

Answer (score 7):

[String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) is in the BCL in .NET 4

Answer (score 6):

An " " is an ASCII 32 value, it is no different from any other ASCII character except it "looks" blank.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you need to trim the string, however if you call trim() on a null string you will get an error.

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Trim())
```

This will error out.

You will need to do something like

```
if (Not string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) AndAlso s.Trim()!=string.Empty)
```

This will verify that the string isn't null or empty, if has something it will trim and then verify its not empty.

## Edit

Thanks Slough for helping me with my VB syntax. I'm a C# guy need to brush up on vb's syntax

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET you'll need to use a test like this:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(test) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(test.Trim()) Then
```

The `OrElse` prevents the NullException from occurring on the `test.Trim()`

Comment: interesting, is there a C# equivalent to OrElse?

Comment: VB uses Or and OrElse where as C# uses | and ||

Comment: This has one more test of null than it needs. Better to do: If (s Is Nothing OrElse s.Trim() = String.Empty) Then

Comment: @Martin - Is the extra null test a difference worth worrying about?

Comment: It's not, but Trim() can be an expensive operation compared to checking every character for Char.IsWhiteSpace().

Answer (score 1):

```
public static bool IsNullOrWhite(string s)
{
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    return true;

  for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(s, i))
      return false;

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just want to trim the string (of spaces) before checking it?

```
Dim test As String = " "
If test.Trim().Length = 0 Then // Best option as long as string is guaranteed not to be null.
//  If test = Nothing OrElse test.Trim().Length = 0 Then // If string can be null.
    MessageBox.Show("Empty String")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Not Emtpy String")
End If
```

Comment: Also, note that you can test for `test.Trim() == string.Empty`. It's a matter of readability for you personally (I don't believe there's any performance different, as both checks probably get optimised).

Comment: Except that is test is null ... sorry Nothing in VB.NET it will crash.

Comment: @Petar: Read the commented line. :)

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned, calling Trim() will throw a NullReferenceException if the string is null. I sometimes use `Regex.IsMatch(test, "^ +$")` (hope I have the parameter order right) to test for one or more spaces. The ^ and $ make sure you're matching the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to treat strings containing only whitespace character the same as empty or null strings, then you could use an extension method like this one (sorry, it's in C#):

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsNullOrEmptyOrWhitespace(this string str)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return true;
            return (str.Trim().Length == 0);
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to write:

```
using ExtensionMethods;

string s1 = "  ";
string s2 = "some string";

s1.IsNullOrEmptyOrWhitespace(); //-> returns true
s2.IsNullOrEmptyOrWhitespace(); //-> returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If test Is Nothing OrElse test.Trim().Length = 0 Then ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add an extension method such as was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647643/string-isnullorblank-extension-method) and keep the same ease of use you previously had with `IsNullOrEmpty()`.

Comment: Sigh... Mine is exactly the same answer as Martin's below. Cutting and pasting gets an up vote while providing a link gets a downvote. Must be someone using Lynx who gets irritated by hyperlinks.

Answer (score -1):

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) OrElse str.Trim().Length = 0 Then
  ' ..
End If
```

The following may not work sometime if the str is null as calling a method on null will result in exception.
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(str.Trim()) Then ' exception sometimes
    ...
    End If

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
Dim test As String = " "
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(test.Trim()) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Empty String")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Not Emtpy String")
End If
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: will throw an exception on Trim() with null

Comment: Yeah, I think that was flagged higher up the chain :)