# Is there a way to implement and make use of a "NOT null coalescing" operator?

Tags: c#, .net, null-coalescing-operator, null-coalescing

Is there a **not** *null coalescing* operator in `C#` which in case could be used such as:

```
public void Foo(string arg1)
{
    Bar b = arg1 !?? Bar.Parse(arg1);   
}
```

The following case made me think of it:

```
public void SomeMethod(string strStartDate)
{
    DateTime? dtStartDate = strStartDate !?? DateTime.ParseExact(strStartDate, "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

I might not have `strStartDate` information, which in case will be `null` but if i do; i'm always certain that it will be in expected *format*. So instead of initializing `dtStartDate = null` and trying to `parse` and set the value within `try catch` block. It seems to be more useful.

I suppose the answer is no (and there is no such operator `!??` or anything else)
I wonder if there's a way to implement this logic, would it be worth and what would be the cases that it comes useful.

Comment: why don't you use just [conditional ?: Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) ?

Comment: what do you mean by "not null coalescing"? If you wrote what it did in regular "this compiles now" code (using either `if` or *conditional*), what would it look like?

Comment: @Selman22 Isn't *null coalescing* a syntactic sugar for *tenary*? You could `x = x != null ? x : y` instead of `x = x ?? y` aswell. I suppose this is not the case, sorry kardeşim

Comment: @Zefnus you can **NOT** add a new operator to an existing language.If you want it design and create your own language, kardeşim.

Comment: @Zefnus no, the `??` operator is syntactic sugar for "take the first non-null expression"; it is also possible to *represent* that in a *condtional*, but that doesn't mean that `??` is syntactic sugar for a *conditional*

Comment: @MarcGravell well i suppose the syntactic sugar i was looking for was "take the first null expression" in case. And if none it would take a value

Comment: The "take the first null expression" is under consideration (at least, as far as member access) for C# 6 - see my answer

Comment: Some other questions with a similar topic: [Possible pitfalls of using this (extension method based) shorthand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123088/possible-pitfalls-of-using-this-extension-method-based-shorthand), [Evil use of Maybe monad and extension methods in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196031/evil-use-of-maybe-monad-and-extension-methods-in-c), [How to check for nulls in a deep lambda expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854591/how-to-check-for-nulls-in-a-deep-lambda-expression).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mads Torgersen has publicly said that a null-propagating operator is under consideration for the next version of C# (but also emphasised that this doesn't mean it will be there). This would allow code like:

```
var value = someValue?.Method()?.AnotherMethod();
```

where the `?.` returns `null` if the operand (on the left) is `null`, else will evaluate the right hand side. I suspect that would get you a lot of the way here, especially if combined with (say) extension methods; for example:

```
DateTime? dtStartDate = strStartDate?.MyParse();
```

where:

```
static DateTime MyParse(this string value) {
    return DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd.MM.yyyy",
         System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
);
```

However! You could do the same thing *right now* just using extension methods:

```
DateTime? dtStartDate = strStartDate.MyParse();

static DateTime? MyParse(this string value) {
    if(value == null) return null;
    return DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd.MM.yyyy",
         System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
);
```

Comment: That is the answer, thank you. I considered your *right now* suggestion as alternative for using conditional operator

Comment: Do you know if any consideration was given to, instead of only having an operator that maps null to null, having `foo ?.bar : baz` be equivalent [but for `foo` being evaluated only once] to `foo ? foo.bar : baz`?  That would I think both make the syntax more useful and also bring it closer to `? :`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the ternary [conditional operator `?:`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
DateTime? dtStartDate = strStartDate == null ? null : DateTime.ParseExact(…)
```

An operator you proposed isn’t actually easily doable because it has a non-consistent type:

```
DateTime? a = (string)b !?? (DateTime)c;
```

For this expression to work, the compiler would need to know *at compile time* that `b` is null, so that the (null) string value can be assigned to `a`.