# How to check for nulls using LINQ

Tags: linq, null

I have this code. How can I check for null values with the SingleOrDefault method?

```
public static List<ETY.Rol> GetRolesByApplicationAndCompany(this UsuarioContext usuario, int company, int app)
        {
            List<ETY.Company> lCompanies= usuario.Companies;

            var roles = lCompanies.
                SingleOrDefault(e => (e.Id == company)).Applications.
                SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == app).Roles;
            return roles;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean returning null or an empty list if any of the `SingleOrDefault` returns null? In that case:

```
var company = lCompanies.SingleOrDefault(e => (e.Id == company));
if(company != null) {
    var application = company.Applications.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == app);
    if(application!=null) {
        return application.Roles;
    }
}
return null; //Or: return new List<ETY.Rol>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking at a Maybe/IfNotNull extension method ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336775/pipe-forwards-in-c/337846#337846) and [here](http://incrediblejourneysintotheknown.blogspot.com/2008/12/maybe-monad-in-c.html)).

Or use Linq syntax something like this (untested):

```
var q = from company in lCompanies.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == company)
        where company != null
        let application = company.Applications.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == app)
        where application != null
        select application.Roles;
```

([Greg Beech's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927091/checks-nulls-using-linq/1927125#1927125) is better if the Single condition is guaranteed)

Comment: I'm pretty sure your first line won't compile as it will return a single company which is not IEnumerable<Company>.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `SingleOrDefault` you could write a chained query as follows. You lose the semantics of ensuring that there's only a single application or company, but if you know that to always be the case then it shouldn't be a problem.

```
return from c in lCompanies where c.Id == company
       from a in c.Applications where a.Id == app
       select a.Roles;
```