# Shortcut for "null if object is null, or object.member if object is not null"

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to write a generic extension method that let's me do this:

```
this.startDate = startDateXAttribute.NullOrPropertyOf<DateTime>(() =>
{
    return DateTime.Parse(startDateXAttribute.Value);
});
```

`NullOrPropertyOf()` would return `null` if it's used on a `null` object (e.g. if `startDateXAttribute` was `null`), or return the result of a `Func` if it's not null.

What would this extension method look like?

Comment: And this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336775/pipe-forwards-in-c/337846#337846

Comment: ...and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854591/how-to-check-for-nulls-in-a-deep-lambda-expression/854619#854619

Comment: Note to C# language designers: adding something like a null-safe dereferencing operator to the language is likely to be a popular feature. :-)

Comment: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3990187-add-operator-to-c-?tracking_code=594c10a522f8e9bc987ee4a5e2c0b38d

Comment: At this time of writing, such a feature is actually planned for C# 6: see [.NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn"): Language feature status: Null propagating operator `?.`](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's no short form for that; implementing one is a fairly frequently requested feature. The syntax could be something like:

```
x = foo.?bar.?baz;
```

That is, x is null if foo or foo.bar are null, and the result of foo.bar.baz if none of them are null.

We considered it for C# 4 but it did not make it anywhere near the top of the priority list. We'll keep it in mind for hypothetical future versions of the language.

UPDATE: C# 6 will have this feature. See http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883 for a discussion of the design considerations.

Comment: hypothetical? I hope MS is not going to drop C# so soon ;)

Comment: @vc: I remind you all that Eric's musings about hypothetical features of unannounced future products that do not exist today and might never exist are *for entertainment purposes only* and do not constitute any promise to deliver any product with any feature at any time.

Comment: you're my definition for cautious

Comment: @Eric: Congratulations. You sound like a lawyer!

Comment: @EricLippert wouldn't `?.` be better? The first question mark style is more consistent with semantics of ternary operator (which is more like checking a condition), and then an ending period `.` opens the scope for intellisense to act and list all the existing members. My pick: `x = foo?.bar?.baz;`

Comment: @nawfal: Excellent point.

Comment: @EricLippert Nemerle does the same!

Comment: Update: On [Roslyn's list of language features](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status) this item is "planned". They seem to use `?.` and not `.?`.

Comment: The **"safe navigation operator"** `?.` (for example `var x = a?.b?.c?.d;`) is mentioned [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator.aspx) at MSDN, it received 3,752 votes at the user voice. Hopefully it will be implemented soon, since the equivalent `var x=(a==null)?null:((b==null)?null:((c==null)?null:a.b.c.d));` is just **UGLY.**

Comment: @Matt: C# 6 will have this feature. See http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883

Answer (score 1):

The [XAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute.aspx) provides an [explicit conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986944.aspx) for this:

```
XAttribute startDateXAttribute = // ...

DateTime? result = (DateTime?)startDateXAttribute;
```

For the general case, the best option is probably this:

```
DateTime? result = (obj != null) ? (DateTime?)obj.DateTimeValue : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?  I think it breaks down if you pass a non-nullable value type, but it should work when you're using nullable types.
Please let me know if there is something I've overlooked.

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static T NullOrPropertyOf<T>(this XAttribute attribute, Func<string, T> converter)
    {
        if (attribute == null)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
        return converter.Invoke(attribute.Value);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<string, DateTime?> convertDT = (string str) =>
        {
            DateTime datetime;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(str, out datetime))
            {
                return datetime;
            }
            return null;
        };
        Func<string, string> convertStr = (string str) =>
        {
            return str;
        };
        XAttribute x = null;
        Console.WriteLine(x.NullOrPropertyOf<string>(convertStr));
        Console.WriteLine(x.NullOrPropertyOf<DateTime?>(convertDT));
        XName t = "testing";
        x = new XAttribute(t, "test");
        Console.WriteLine(x.NullOrPropertyOf<string>(convertStr));
        x = new XAttribute(t, DateTime.Now);
        Console.WriteLine(x.NullOrPropertyOf<DateTime?>(convertDT));
    }
}
```

Comment: You dont need to specify the parameter type of lambda once you write down the type on lhs.