# Safe Navigation Operator in C#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shortcut for “null if object is null, or object.member if object is not null”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817930/shortcut-for-null-if-object-is-null-or-object-member-if-object-is-not-null)

Some languages have a safe navigation operator that lets you not worry about null reference exceptions.

Example of the language [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/):

```
String lname = person.Name.ToLowerCase(); //throws exception if Name is null
String lname = person.Name?.ToLowerCase();//lname will be null if Name was null
```

How can I accomplish something similar to this in C#?  My solution so far is an extension method like this:

```
public static T o<T>(this T obj) where T : new()
{
            return obj != null ? obj : new T();
}
//used like: String lname = person.o().Name; //returns null if person was null
```

However, this only works in some cases.

Comment: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3990187-add-operator-to-c-?tracking_code=594c10a522f8e9bc987ee4a5e2c0b38d

Comment: At this time of writing, such a feature is actually planned for C# 6: see [.NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn"): Language feature status: Null propagating operator `?.`](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For such cases I tend to use an extension method called `IfNotNull`:

```
public static OUT IfNotNull<IN, OUT>(this IN v, Func<IN, OUT> f) 
  where IN : class where OUT : class
{
  return v == null ? null : f(v);
}
```

More sophisticated is to introduce the notion of a Maybe . An example was brought by derick bailey [here](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/derickbailey/archive/2010/09/29/monads-in-c-which-part-is-the-monad.aspx).

**Update:**

As of [C# 6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx) there is now a null-propagating operator which syntax-wise looks exactly like the Groovy one.

Comment: This seems like a pretty good solution. Allows you to not break method chaining and not have to introduce a temporary variable, which are the main reasons I want to use a safe navigation operator.

Comment: This is dependent on `OUT` being a nullable type. You can extend this to all types by: 1. remove `where OUT : class`, 2. alter the body to `return v == null ? default(OUT) : f(v);`.

Comment: How does v derive from o? That's the whole point, to be able to do sth with o if it is not null.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the short-circuiting **[null-conditional member access operator `?.`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx)** that was introduced in C# language version 6 (rolled out in Visual Studio 2015).

The remainder of my answer was written for earlier versions of the C# language which did not have the `?.` operator.

---

Generally speaking, if you're in a situation where you are accessing a deeply "nested" property, such as `outermostObject.a.b.c.X`, you should probably consider re-designing your code, as such an access could indicate that you're violating established OO principles (such as the principle of least knowledge, a.k.a. Law of Demeter).

Some other options:

**First**, an anti-suggestion — don't do this:

```
string lname = null;
try
{
    lname = Person.Name.ToLower();
}
catch (NullReferenceException ex) { }  // inefficient and ugly
```

**Second**, using something like a `Maybe` monad — you can define such a type yourself. It's basically a `Nullable<T>` that implements `IEnumerable<T>` such that it returns an empty sequence when no value is set, or a sequence of exactly one element if a value is set. You'd then use it as follows:

```
Maybe<string> personName = person.Name;
var lname = (from name in personName select name.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Third**, and probably the easiest and most practical solution, as suggested by ulrichb:

```
var lname = person.Name != null ? person.Name.ToLower() : null;
```

---

**P.S.**, since we're already on the topic of checking for `null`, don't forget to check whether `person` is `null` before accessing its `Name` property... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about returning a null from something that's guaranteed to not be null, but for guaranteeing an object reference, you can use the [Null Coalescing Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) `??`

Something like:

```
string lname = (person.Name??String.Empty).ToLower();
```

It will return an empty string instead of null for the null case, but it will work.

Returning an empty string makes more sense than returning a null; if you return a null, it will throw again if you chain another operator onto it.

Comment: You could write a `ToLowerCase` extension method, but I'd probably just use the built-in `ToLower` method on the string object.

Comment: +1 for using the `??` operator.

Comment: ?? is my favorite C# operator.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't exist in C# today, but you can write it with `SelectMany`.

```
String lname = from _ in person.Name from s in _.ToUpper() select s;
```

or

```
String lname = person.Name.SelectMany(_ => _.ToUpper(), s => s);
```

(That was Bart De Smet's proposal in [his PDC 2010 talk on the future of LINQ](http://player.microsoftpdc.com/Session/bfa72307-6534-41ad-bcf7-0f4fb9280515). See slide #6.)

Comment: Note that `SelectMany` in this case isn't the usual LINQ `SelectMany` but a custom `SelectMany` created to implement the `Maybe` monad.