# Setting the value of a variable based on the result of a fetch in C#

Tags: c#

```
var d = get(x).Title;
var e = get(y).Title;
```

The getting of Title gives an exception if get(y) returns null. However what I need is for e to be null if get(y) is null and there to be no exception generated. I can do this with two steps of get(y) but I want to only do the get(y) one time.

Is there some easy one line way that I can with just one get(y) and with one line of code set e to null if get(y) is null or the actual value if get(y) does not return a null?

Comment: what's more important? only calling get(y) once or not assigning an intermediate variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var z = get(y);
var e = z != null ? z.Title : null;
```

You can also use extension methods like those:

```
    public static TResult IfNotNull<T, TResult>(this T obj, Func<T, TResult> selector)
        where T : class
    {
        return obj.IfNotNull(selector, default(TResult));
    }

    public static TResult IfNotNull<T, TResult>(this T obj, Func<T, TResult> selector, TResult valueIfNull)
        where T : class
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return valueIfNull;
        return selector(obj);
    }

...

    var e = get(y).IfNotNull(_ => _.Title);
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. This solution looks very interesting. I tried it and it seems to work okay so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = get(x) != null ? get(x).Title : null;
```

Since you state that only one call of `get(x)` `get(y)` is allowed you could write this as follows

```
  var X = get(x);
  var d = X != null ? X.Title : null;
```

That is the shortest way to write the code but I think a more clear way to write all of this would be to handle this with some form of an extension method of a function call since this is something that you are having to do to multiple variables

Example Extension Methods

```
public static TypeOfTitle GetTitle(this TypeOfget x)
{
   return x != null ? x.Title : null;
}
```

Then call this as follows

```
var d = get(x).GetTitle();
```

Comment: This won't compile... both operands of the ?? operator must have the same type

Comment: WOW I have never seen this operator before !!

Comment: Samantha needs to return Title if get(y) is null, null otherwise.  Your code will return get(y) and if that's null, return get(y).Title.

Comment: -1 - Even if this compiled, if `get(x)` returns a `null`, then `get(x).Title` will try to execute, resulting in a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: I noticed and fixed it...completely wrong. woops

Comment: the OP stated only one call of get(y) was allowed. You're calling get(y) twice if it isn't null.

Comment: But is this not back to the needing to do get(x) twice ?

Comment: @codesparkle changed after I wrote my answer correcting

Comment: @SamanthaJ I've corrected my code for those issues.

Comment: Your edit does not include a valid extension method, nor a valid invocation of one.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram thanks, it just needed the this? and yes it does

Comment: No, the invocation was still wrong, but I have corrected that for you rather than be pedantic. Missing parentheses.

Comment: Thank you. I think both this answer and the one by Thomas will do what I needed. I'm not actually sure which to mark correct as both look good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inline conditional statement (or, ternary operator), like so:

```
var e = get(y) != null ? get(y).Title : null;
```

However, you might want to take the 'primitive' route (I know, I know, one-liners are all the rage), if for nothing else but to minimise the calls to `get` (which you do state as a concern), which would simply be:

```
string e = null;
var somethingOrOther = get(y);
if (somethingOrOther != null) {
    e = somethingOrOther;
}
```

To my knowledge, I'm afraid it's one or the other - someone else might know something I don't, or Jon Skeet might concoct some evil for you, but this is where I stand (anything else would seem only to be variations of the same approaches).

Furthermore, since now being aware of a [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817930/shortcut-for-null-if-object-is-null-or-object-member-if-object-is-not-null), but for completeness, I'll quote Eric Lippert's on *"null if object is null, or object.member if object is not null"*:

> There's no short form for that; implementing one is a fairly
>   frequently requested feature.

Comment: But this needs get(y) to be performed twice :-(

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a terinary operator:

```
var e = (get(y) == null ? null : get(y).Title).
```

If `get(y)` is an expensive operation, you'll want to cache it in another variable.

Comment: Still hoping for a solution with no other variable. The ?? below looked good but another poster said it would not work :-(

Comment: @SamanthaJ: You can't do it without another variable unless you call get(y) twice.  Even the null coalescing operator (written improperly below) requires two calls to get(y).

Comment: @SamanthaJ, there have been calls for a `?.` operator, which would theoretically allow you to say `get(x)?.Title` without a null check, but there have been no announcements about whether to include that in a future version of C#, and it is obviously not there now.

Comment: @SamanthaJ: unless this is code golf, use another variable.