# Best syntax for a = (x == null) ? null : x.func()

Tags: c#, syntax

Basic question here - I have many lines of code that look something like:

```
var a = (long_expression == null) ? null : long_expression.Method();
```

Similar lines repeat a lot in this function. `long_expression` is different every time. I am trying to find **a way to avoid repeating `long_expression`, but keeping this compact**. Something like the opposite of `operator ??`. For the moment I'm considering just giving in and putting it on multiple lines like:

```
var temp = long_expression;
var a = (temp == null) ? null : temp.Method();
```

But I was curious if there is some clever syntax I don't know about that would make this more concise.

Comment: `var a = temp ? null : temp.Method();` I think you meant to have `var a = temp == null ? null : temp.method();` Small detail though

Comment: I think your current method is the way to go.

Comment: "Best syntax" under the constraint "language == C#", or for stuff like that in general? Obviously something like this can be written rather better in a functional language, using (applicative) functors / monads and suchlike.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Yeah, this operation is precisely `>>=` for the `Maybe` monad.

Comment: Although it's minor, I really think reversing the logic to: "long_expression != null ? long_expression.Method() : null" is more clear - with the important logic coming first.  It's also consistent with logic such as "if (long_expression != null) do_something", which is how this would be written if it wasn't a variable initialization.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check for nulls in a deep lambda expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854591/how-to-check-for-nulls-in-a-deep-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Well, you *could* use an extension method like this:

```
public static TResult NullOr<TSource, TResult>(this TSource source,
    Func<TSource, TResult> func) where TSource : class where TResult : class
{
    return source == null ? null : func(source);
}
```

Then:

```
var a = some_long_expression.NullOr(x => x.Method());
```

Or (depending on your version of C#)

```
var a = some_long_expression.NullOr(Foo.Method);
```

where `Foo` is the type of `some_long_expression`.

I don't think I *would* do this though. I'd just use the two line version. It's simpler and less clever - and while "clever" is fun for Stack Overflow, it's not usually a good idea for real code.

Comment: Beat me to it! I was about to post something like this.

Comment: I've always disliked extension-methods that runs on null-references. Calling methods on null should IMO always throw a Null Reference Exception. I know extension-methods are in fact static helper methods, but that's not always clear to the reader of the code.

Comment: It may be inconsistent, but it's also incredibly useful. There are methods which previously, had to be static class methods, that are much more discoverable as extension methods that operate on null values. Adding an extension method of IsNullOrWhiteSpace on String is a great example.

Comment: @JonSkeet: You said you wouldn't use this method; is that personal preference, or is there some risk / impact to using it?  I ask as this looks like an ideal workaround to me (until we get a `?.` operator (https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3990187-add-operator-to-c) or a `!??` operator which acts as a reverse `??`)

Comment: @JohnLBevan: Personal preference - I generally favour simple code over "clever" code. I don't know of any *risk* in using it.

Comment: NB: found a side effect of trying to be clever: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String NullSafe` (using slightly different version of the method which catered for both reference and value types: http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/frankb/archive/2008/02/02/Using-C_2300_-3.0-Extension-methods-and-Lambda-expressions-to-avoid-nasty-Null-Checks.aspx)

Comment: I can't get the code to compile.  it complains about not finding TResult... googled for a bit but didn't figure it out

Comment: @wintersylf: `TResult` is a type parameter in the generic method. Without seeing what you're trying, I can't see where your mistake is - but this code *does* compile.

Comment: are there any includes I need to have, and/or can I drop this into any namespace/class/file?

Comment: @wintersylf: Well you'll need a `using` directive for the `System` namespace in the place where you're declaring the `NullOr` method, and you'll need a `using` directive for whichever namespace contains the class that declares the extension method, wherever you want to *use* the extension method, but that's all.

Answer (score 49):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1943617/8155) insightful.

By doing this assignment, you are propagating the null deeper into the system.  You'll have to write your null handling condition again (and again and again) to handle these propagations.

Instead of allowing execution to continue with nulls, replace the null with a better representation (quoted from link)

> 1. If the null represents an empty collection, use an empty collection.
> 2. If the null represents an exceptional case, throw an Exception.
> 3. If the null represents an accidentally uninitialized value, explicitly initialize it.
> 4. If the null represents a legitimate value, test for it - or even better use a NullObject that performs a null op.

In particular, replacing a null collection reference with an empty collection has saved me many null tests.

Comment: I very much agree; but unfortunately, in many situations you find yourself working with an API or legacy code that uses null a lot.

Answer (score 5):

```
var x = "";

/* try null instead */
string long_expression = "foo";

var a = ((x = long_expression) == null) ? null : x.ToUpper();

/* writes "FOO" (or nothing) followed by newline */
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

The type of the initialization value of `x` must be compatible to the type of `long_expression` (here: `string`). Works with the [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) C# compiler, version 2.10.8.1 (from Debian package mono-gmcs=2.10.8.1-4).

Comment: @MirceaChirea OK, then. Does it *work* in C#?  I cannot test here.

Comment: yes it does. var just tells the compiler to infer the type from the expression; particularly useful with long types like IEnumerable<MyLongClassName>.

Comment: @MirceaChirea Thanks, I looked it up in the [Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) already :) Testing with [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) now.

Answer (score 5):

I think the C# language could really use a new operator for this sort of logic - it's quite common, and an operator would simplify countless lines of code out there.

We need something along the lines of the "??" or "if null then" operator, but that works as special '.' dot operator with a "if not null" condition.  For "??", the first '?' is like the 'if' part of the "?:" if-then, and the second '?' represents 'null' like for nullable types.  I think we need a ".?" operator which works just like '.', except it simply evaluates to null if the left expression is null instead of throwing an exception.  I guess it would be a "dot not null" operator (OK, so maybe ".!?" would be more logical, but let's not go there).

So, your oh-so-common example could lose the redundant symbol name like this:

```
var a = long_expression.?Method();
```

There is a ton of C# code out there with nested null checks that would benefit greatly.  Just think how nice it would if this:

```
if (localObject != null)
{
    if (localObject.ChildObject != null)
    {
        if (localObject.ChildObject.ChildObject != null)
            localObject.ChildObject.ChildObject.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

could become just:

```
localObject.?ChildObject.?ChildObject.?DoSomething();
```

There is also a ton of code where null checks that should be there are missing, resulting in occasional runtime errors.  So, actually using the new '.?' operator by default would eliminate such problems... It's perhaps unfortunate that we couldn't reverse the behavior of '.' and '.?' at this point, so only the new '.?' throws an exception if the left side is null - it would be the cleaner and more logical way to go, but breaking changes are very bad.  Although, one could argue that this particular change would be likely to fix a lot of hidden problems, and unlikely to break anything (only code that expects a null ref exception to be thrown).  Oh, well... one can always dream...

The only downside to checking for the null is really the slight performance hit, which is most assuredly why '.' doesn't check for null.  But, I really think the ability to just use '.?' when you care about performance (and know the left side will never be null) would have been the better way to go.

On a similar note, having 'foreach' check for and ignore a null collection would have also been so much nicer.  No more need to wrap most 'foreach' statements with "if (collection != null)", or worse, develop the common habit of always using empty collections instead of null ... which is fine in some cases, but an even worse performance issue than the null check when this is done in complex object trees where the majority of the collections are empty (which I've seen a lot).  I think the good intention of not having 'foreach' check for null to provide better performance has backfired in the majority of cases.

Anders, it's never too late to make such changes, and add a compiler switch to enable them!

Comment: that's called the null safe navigator. See here for a response by a member of the C# language team: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3818256/45583

Comment: The opposite of ?? is obviously !??  which is what the operator should be.

Comment: @DavidB - we're not talking about an opposite of '??', but a null safe version of '.', which is a completely different operator.  My reference to '??' was only background as to why '.?' might make sense, but others have apparently already come to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an extension method for whatever type long_expression evaluates to:

```
public static object DoMethod(this MyType pLongExpression)
{
   return pLongExpression == null ? null : pLongExpression.Method();
}
```

This will be callable on any `MyType` reference, even if that reference is `null`.

Comment: I've always disliked extension-methods that runs on null-references. Calling methods on null should IMO always throw a Null Reference Exception. I know extension-methods are in fact static helper methods, but that's not always clear to the reader of the code.

Comment: From OP - the long expression is different every time (can also mean the return type).

Answer (score 0):

You could put `long_expression == null` into a function with a short name and just call that function each time.

Comment: that is, if this is the same `long_expression` everywhere

Comment: That was my understanding of the question. Is that not the case?

Comment: That would be too easy :D Updated the question; it's different everywhere.

Comment: thats how i got it (lots of different long expressions)

Comment: @tenfour If `long_expression` is different each time, how do you think you could avoid writing it out?

Comment: @Daniel: exactly. That *is* the question.

Comment: Oh I misread the question. I didn't realize that `long_expression` was showing up twice in the same line. If it's only there once, you can't get around writing it each time, but if it shows up twice, there's definitely a way to get around it as Jon Skeet has done.

Answer (score 0):

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)) 
    x.func()