# Extending LINQ to accept nullable enumerables

Tags: c#, .net, linq

While working with Linq extensions it's normal to see code like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> enumerable = GetEnumerable();
int sum = 0;
if (enumerable != null)
{
    sum = enumerable.Sum();
}
```

In order to enhance the code quality, I wrote the following extension method that checks for nullable enumerables and breaks the linq execution.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> IgnoreIfEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    if (enumerable == null) yield break;
    foreach (var item in enumerable)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

So, I can refactor the code to be like this:

```
var sum = GetEnumerable().IgnoreIfEmpty().Sum();
```

---

My questions now:

1. What penalties are associated with my extension method at runtime?
2. Is it's a good practice to extend linq that way?

**Update:**
My target framework is: 3.5

Comment: `IgnoreIfEmpty` isn't a great name, since "Ignore" is vague, and an empty enumerable is different from a null one.

Comment: If you have control over the `GetEnumerable` methods you should really be returning empty collections instead of nulls.

Comment: @DarrenYoung, I have no control over GetEnumerable. plus null is expected return.

Comment: That is not ignoring it if it's empty; it's converting a null to an empty sequence. You should call it `EmptyIfNull()` or something like that.

Comment: I use an EmptyIfNull method like that, it seemed to fit naming style with the DefaultIfEmpty

Comment: Maybe GetEnumerable() would return an empty enumerable insted of null [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969993/is-it-better-to-return-null-or-empty-collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969993/is-it-better-to-return-null-or-empty-collection)

Comment: @msa I'd argue returning null in place of an enumerable is unexpected.  MS guidelines agree https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11267819/8155

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. You're going to have a method call overhead, it will be negligible unless you are running it in a tight loop or a performance criticial scenario. It's but a shadow in comparison to something like a database call or writing to a file system. Note that the method is probably not going to be inlined, since it's an enumerator.
2. It's all about readability / maintainability. What do I expect to happen when I see `GetEnumerable().IgnoreIfEmpty().Sum();`? In this case, it makes sense.

Note that with C# 6 we can use the following syntax: `GetEnumerable()?.Sum()` which returns an `int?`. You could write `GetEnumerable()?.Sum() ?? 0` or `GetEnumerable()?.Sum().GetValueOrDefault()` to get a non-null integer that will default to zero.

If you are truly concerned with performance, you could also slightly refactor your method so that it's not an enumerator. This may increase the chance of inlining, although I have no idea of the 'arcane' logic of the JIT compiler:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> IgnoreIfEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    if (enumerable == null) return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    return enumerable;
}
```

More generally about extending Linq, I think it is perfectly fine as long as the code makes sense. MSDN even has [an article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc981895.aspx) about it. If you look at the standard [`Where`, `Select`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e73922753675387a) methods in Linq, and forget about the performance optimizations they have in there, the methods are all mostly one-liner methods.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that my target framework is 3.5

Comment: @Tyress, why wouldn't it work? The return type is the exact same type as the parameter type. Did you still have a `yield break` statement in there?

Comment: @msa Everything in the answer should apply to .NET 3.5, except the C# 6 side note. Note that you may want to upgrade your toolset, it's almost 10 years old!

Comment: Actually I think null conditional operator should work fine on .NET 3.5 as long as your compiler is C#6 compatible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921701/does-c-sharp-6-0-work-for-net-4-0

Comment: @Bas oh, yes I did have the yield break statement. Awesome.

Comment: @Bas, unfortunately it's a legacy project. we are rewriting it now from scratch but we have to maintain the old one

Comment: @msa What version of Visual Studio are you using to compile the project? If it's Visual Studio 2010 or later, you are already using a later version of the C# language than was released with .Net 3.5

Comment: And if you write the code like this, then you don't really need the extension method because the caller code can also be reduced to a one-liner: `int sum = (enumerable ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>()).Sum()`.

Answer (score 40):

> What penalties are associated with my extension method at runtime?

Your extension method is transformed into a state-machine, so there's the minimal overhead of that, but that shouldn't be noticeable.

> Is it's a good practice to extend linq that way?

In your question you state:

> While working with Linq extensions it's normal to see code like this (*insert enumerable null check here*)

And I beg to differ. The *common practice* says [don't return null where an `IEnumerable<T>` is expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969993/is-it-better-to-return-null-or-empty-collection). Most cases should return an empty collection (or `IEnumerable`), leaving `null` to the **exceptional**, because [null is not empty](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/14/null-is-not-empty/). This would make your method entirely redundant. Use `Enumerable.Empty<T>` where needed.

Comment: Definitely agree with preferring empty collections over null. Null should be used sparingly and with clarity, for anything, not just collections. Lost count of how many bugs come from null references.

Answer (score 14):

You can skip the additional extension method and use [null coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) - this is what it's for, and a one-time check for nullability should be a lot more efficient than another state machine:

```
IEnumerable<int> enumerable = GetEnumerable();
int sum = 0;

sum = (enumerable ?? Enumerable.Empty<int>()).Sum();
```

Comment: Well, when we say "a lot more efficient" we can't be talking about more than a matter of milliseconds, can we?

Comment: @Casey - The bigger the initial list, the bigger performance impact.

Comment: Or in C#6, just `int sum = enumerable?.Sum() ?? 0`.

Comment: @w.b. Oh, I thought the OP was just returning the list and not iterating over it again.  You're right.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the times we write a lot of code just because we are enchanted by the beauty of our creation - **not because we really need it** - and then we call it abstraction, reusability, extensibility, etc..

Is this raw piece less readable or less extensible or less reuseable or slower :

```
var sum = GetEnumerable().Where(a => a != null).Sum();
```

The less code you write - the less code you test - keep it simple. 
BTW - it is good to write extension methods if you can justify it.

Comment: I agree with your statements on keeping things simple to some degree, but the code you give does something very different than the code of the question: You check for elements being `null`, while the questions checks if the enumerable itself is `null`.

Comment: @amulware enumerable should not be null - if it is null then the developer is breaking standard practices. Return empty collections - not null. If enumerable is null then return - why compute ? Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why is my answer downvoted - any one in specific having any specific complains ? Or even am free to downvote all responses ?