# Good lambda expression or better way to reduce for each loop

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get sub folders of a root folder. And i am able to get it through the below code.
But has a issue when the sub folder has a sub folder in it and i over come it writing a second for each loop. But what if the second sub folder has a sub folder under it.
So there will be an infinte for each loop, so i have to overcome it.
Any help is worthfull.Thanks in advance.

```
foreach (Folder.Folder folder in FolderService.Instance.GetSubFolders(userContext, folderID))
            {
                folderById.Add(folder.FolderID, folder);
                foreach (Folder.Folder sfolder in FolderService.Instance.GetSubFolders(userContext, folder.FolderID))
                {
                    folderById.Add(sfolder.FolderID, sfolder);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Checkout my related question - some of the answers may be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308481/writing-the-f-recursive-folder-visitor-in-c-seq-vs-ienumerable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perfect place for recursion:

```
... TraverseFolder(rootFolderID, userContext)
{
    var folderById = new ...;
    TraverseFolder(folderById, rootFolderID, userContext);

    return folderById;
}

void TraverseFolder(folderById, folderID, userContext)
{
    var folders = FolderService.Instance.GetSubFolders(userContext, folderID);
    foreach(var folder in folders)
    {
        folderById.Add(folder.FolderID, folder);
        TraverseFolder(folder.FolderID);
    }
}
```

Theoretically, you can have [recursive lambdas](http://blogs.msdn.com/madst/archive/2007/05/11/recursive-lambda-expressions.aspx), but they are waay too complicated.

Comment: Hi anton i am totally confused 
are they  two separate methods

Comment: that is to spare copying/merging the dictionary/list.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a good reason for the dictionary to not be at field level rather than passing it through the recursive call?

```
Dictionary<string, int> folderById = new Dictionary<string,int>();
public void Start()
{
    // code for initial context + folder id
    RecurseFolders(userContext, folderId);
}

public void RecurseFolders(string userContext, int folderId)
{
    foreach (Folder.Folder folder in FolderService.Instance.GetSubFolders(userContext, folderID)) {
        folderById.Add(folder.FolderID, folder);
        RecurseFolders(userContext, folder.folderId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two additional samles using labdas. The first uses a function declared locally to recurse over the items (DirectoryInfos in this case) and the second uses an instance method.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string path = @"d:\temp";

        Func<DirectoryInfo, IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo>> func = null;
        func = (folder) => {
            return new[] { folder }.Concat(folder.GetDirectories().SelectMany(x => func(x)));
        };

        IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> dirs = (new DirectoryInfo(path)).GetDirectories().SelectMany(x => func(x));

        IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> dirs2 = GetSubDirs(new DirectoryInfo(path));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> GetSubDirs(DirectoryInfo dir) {
        yield return dir;
        foreach (var subDir in GetSubDirs(dir)) yield return subDir;
    }

    // method 2 even shorter
    public static IEnumerable<Directory> GetSubDirs2(DirectoryInfo dir) {
        return new[] { dir }.Concat(dir.GetDirectories().SelectMany(x => GetSubDirs2(x)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to write recursive traversal using recursive lambda expression and using `SelectMany` method from LINQ:

```
Func<string, IEnumerable<string>> folders = null;
folders = s =>
  Directory.GetDirectories(s).SelectMany(dir =>
    Enumerable.Concat(new[] { dir }, folders(dir)));

foreach (var d in folders("C:\\Tomas\\Writing\\Academic"))
  Console.WriteLine(d);
```

The first line declares the lambda expression in advance, because we use it later inside its definition. This is not a problem, because it will be used after it has been initialized, but the C# compiler requires that we declare it earlier.

The body of the lambda expression calls `SelectMany`, which calls the given lambda expression for each element of the input sequence and concatenates all returned sequences - our lambda returns the current directory `dir` and then all recursively calculated subdirectories of `dir`.

This is probably not particularly efficient, but it definitely shows how you can use lambda functions to write short code (it could be optimized however, F# libraries do that, because this is more common pattern in F#).

Just for comparison, the same thing in F# looks like this:

```
let folders s = seq {
  for dir in Directory.GetDirectories(s) 
    yield dir
    yield! folders dir }
```

The code uses sequence expressions which are like C# iterators. `yield` corresponds to `yield return` and `yield!` yields all elements of a sequence (it is like iterating over it using `foreach` and yielding individual elements using `yield return`, but more efficient).

Answer (score 0):

I got it done . Here's the code.

```
 private List<Folder.Folder> GetAllF(AbstractUserContext userContext, string folderID)
    {
        List<Folder.Folder> listFold = new List<Folder.Folder>();
        foreach (Folder.Folder folder in FolderService.Instance.GetSubFolders(userContext, folderID))
        {
            listFold.Add(folder);
            listFold.AddRange(GetAllF(userContext,folder.FolderID));
        }
        return listFold;
    }
```